# ASP.NET Core 7 : Cannot resolve 'xxx' from root provider because it requires scoped service 'yyy'

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, entity-framework-core

Frequent error but I was not able to find solution form similar questions.

Error:

> Cannot resolve 'Domain.Interface.Service.IUserManagement' from root provider because it requires scoped service 'Application.DataAccess.EF.DatabaseContext'.

Program.cs

```
SerilogSetup.BootstrapSetup();

try
{
    var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
    builder.Configuration.AddJsonFile("appsettingsAmbiente.json");

    builder.Services.RegisterApplicationServices(builder);
    builder.ConfigureBuilderMiddleware();

    // Add services to the container.
    var app = builder.Build();

    app.ConfigureAppMiddleware();


    app.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "default",
        pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

    app.Run();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Log.Fatal(ex, "Application terminated unexpectedly");
}
finally
{
    Log.CloseAndFlush();
}
```

Initializer class

```
public static partial class ServiceInitializer
{
    public static IServiceCollection RegisterApplicationServices(this IServiceCollection services, WebApplicationBuilder builder)
    {
        services.MapSettings();    
        services.AddTransient<ILoggingService, LoggingService>();

        AddAuthorizationAndAuthentication(services);        

        RegisterDataAccessDependencies(services);
        RegisterBusinessLayerDependencies(services);

        services.AddHttpContextAccessor();

        SerilogSetup.StandardSetup(services, builder);

        services.AddControllersWithViews().AddJsonOptions(options => options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = null);            services.AddControllersWithViews().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();    
        return services;
    }

    private static void RegisterDataAccessDependencies(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<DatabaseContext>((serviceProvider, optionsBuilder) => optionsBuilder
            .UseOracle(DbOptions.Current?.ConnectionStrings?.AppDB ?? string.Empty)
            .LogTo(Log.Logger.Debug, LogLevel.Debug, null)
            .EnableSensitiveDataLogging()
        );

        services.AddScoped<IDatabaseContext, DatabaseContext>();
        services.AddTransient<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>();
    }

    private static void RegisterBusinessLayerDependencies(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddTransient<IUserManagement, UserManagement>();
    }

    private static IServiceCollection MapSettings(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
        AppOptions appOptions = new();
        DbOptions dbSettings = new();
        LogOptions logOptions = new();

        services.ConfigureOptions<AppOptionsSetup>();
        services.ConfigureOptions<DbOptionsSetup>();
        services.ConfigureOptions<LogOptionsSetup>();

        return services;
    }

    private static IServiceCollection AddAuthorizationAndAuthentication(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddCookie(options =>
        {
            options.AccessDeniedPath = $@"{AppOptions.Current.PercorsoErrore}/403";
        });

        services.AddControllersWithViews().AddJsonOptions(options => options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = null);
        services.AddControllersWithViews().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();
        services.AddControllers(options => { options.Filters.Add<AuditAuthorizationFilter>(); });

        return services;
    }
}
```

Context class

```
public class DatabaseContext : DbContext, IDatabaseContext
{
    private readonly ILoggerFactory _loggerFactory;

    #region Ctor
    public DatabaseContext(DbContextOptions<DatabaseContext> options, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
     : base(options)
    {
        _loggerFactory = loggerFactory;
        ChangeTracker.QueryTrackingBehavior = QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking;
        this.ChangeTracker.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
    }
...
}
```

UserManagement

```
public class UserManagement : IUserManagement
{
    private readonly ILogger _logger;
    Domain.Interface.Service.UtenteCorrente _utente;
    private readonly IOptions<UserOptions> userSettings;
    private readonly IOptions<AppOptions> appSettings;
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor;

    public UserManagement(IOptions<UserOptions> us, IHttpContextAccessor hca, ILogger logger, IOptions<AppOptions> aps, IUnitOfWork uo)
    {
        userSettings = us;
        appSettings = aps;
        contextAccessor = hca;
        uow = uo;
        _logger = logger;
        // ... 
    }
}
```

Comment: See [Note](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/dependency-injection#scoped)

Comment: Use [Scope validation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/web-host?view=aspnetcore-7.0#scope-validation)

Comment: i have no singleton service

Comment: scope validation is not for WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov any other idea? thanks

Comment: @gt.guybrush change this from `services.AddTransient<IUserManagement, UserManagement>();` to `services.AddScoped<IUserManagement, UserManagement>();`

Comment: in this way i get: Cannot resolve scoped service 'Domain.Interface.Service.IUserManagement' from root provider.

Comment: but if i add  optionsLifetime: ServiceLifetime.Transient to AddDbContext got it working